# Failed to build: Error parsing reference: "microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base" is not a valid repository/tag:

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I got the below error when build docker for console application using .net core.

> Step 1/15 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
>   Error parsing reference: "microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

My Dockerfile looks below

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ConsoleApp2/ConsoleApp2.csproj ConsoleApp2/
RUN dotnet restore ConsoleApp2/ConsoleApp2.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/ConsoleApp2
RUN dotnet build ConsoleApp2.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish ConsoleApp2.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp2.dll"]
```

My docker version is

> Docker version 17.03.1-ce-rc1, build 3476dbf

Can some one suggest what I am doing wrong in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-stage builds (which added the `FROM ... AS ...` syntax along with multiple `FROM` lines) require 17.05 or newer. You'll need to upgrade your docker server.

For more details on multi-stage builds, see: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/