# The FROM ... AS Command gives parsing error in linux

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

The Docker example for .NET Core's documentation has the first statement as:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
```

This commands works on the windows system but giving problems on linux:

```
Step 1/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk AS build-env
Error parsing reference: "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk AS build-env" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

I tried removing the `AS <name>` which worked, but now have a scenario where the name needs to be used.

Below is the code snippet for the basic example

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Comment: docker version ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55640783/596285

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the docker version first.
Multistage builds is a relatively new feature:

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) states:

> Multi-stage builds are a new feature requiring Docker 17.05 or higher on the daemon and client.

So the chances are that you should just upgrade the docker version...