# Dockerfile ot working in Linux Sever but working in Ubuntu VM

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I have a Dockerfile and it's working fine in Ubuntu VM. However, the same Dockerfile does not build in Linux Server.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.7-slim as builder-image
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  python3-dev  gcc libc-dev musl-dev  libffi-dev g++  cargo && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python3.9 -m venv /home/myuser/venv
ENV PATH="/home/myuser/venv/bin:$PATH"
RUN /home/myuser/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
WORKDIR /home/myuser/venv
COPY /data/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir wheel
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt



FROM python:3.9.7-slim
RUN useradd --create-home myuser
COPY --from=builder-image /home/myuser/venv /home/myuser/venv
USER myuser
RUN mkdir /home/myuser/code
WORKDIR /home/myuser/code
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/myuser/venv
ENV PATH="/home/myuser/venv/bin:$PATH"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

docker build -t python-docker_14122021 .

```
Error:

Sending build context to Docker daemon 49.66 kB
Step 1/23 : FROM python:3.9-slim-buster as builder-image
Error parsing reference: "python:3.9-slim-buster as builder-image" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

Comment: What OS and version is the Linux server running for its distro

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52492611/596285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very old `docker` on the server. You need to have at least version `17.06` of `docker` to support multi-staging builds.

Comment: This answer is correct.